# How to Add and subtract var in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a completely nooby on Jquery.
I'm trying to calculate and obviously didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('.a').height();
    var y = $('.b').height();
    $('.c').height(y - x + x);

});
```

I'm close to make it work? :))

https://jsfiddle.net/kav5y0vf/

Comment: make sure to parse the value into whatever you want it to be(float or integer) before doing the operation.

Comment: You can console.log() and see your progress.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? Why is it obvious that it isn't working? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is actually happening?

Comment: Can you guys help? https://jsfiddle.net/kav5y0vf/

Comment: "I'm trying to do some count... " What do you mean? From the code provided (which is good) I still have no idea what it's purpose is. So what do you expect to happen? What is it doing instead?

Comment: I mean "to calculate". I'm using Jquery for 2 days so I just know the basic. I need to set the height based on heights of anothers divs. 
So I would have the divs ".a"  and ".b" with a variable height.
And the Div ".C" is position fixed based on that heights. So, if I could calculate that, for sure I'll have the result that I expect.

Comment: There different methods on height. .a has a lot of padding; did you want to include padding in measurement?

Comment: Your jsFiddle example won't run jQuery unless you include jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var x = $('.a').height();
```

Use

```
var x = $('.a').outerHeight();
```

height() returns height of element with no padding, whereas outerHeight() does.

jsfiddle below:

`https://jsfiddle.net/kav5y0vf/2/`

Comment: And border as well

Comment: Yes. In that case only padding has been added

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$('ul.logad li.o').height(y - x + x);
```

To

```
$('ul.logad li.o').css('height', (y - x + x) + 'px');
```

Don't know why you need this but y-x+x = y

Comment: True, thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks!!

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to set the height to `y - x` and the top to `x`?